# Change colour of an image

Tags: color, logo, icon, pixlr, apple-preview

I would like to change the colour of the following image (from grey) to red, does anyone know if it is possible to do this with Mac Preview? I couldn't find out how to do it.

Otherwise, is it possible to do this with an online editor like https://pixlr.com/?

[image: image of grey box]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the image essentially has no colour [black/white/grey are not considered 'colours' for this] then Preview cannot do anything useful with it.

You can make it swing the tint between greenish & blueish, you can even then force a white balance change to make it bright blue – but you can't squeeze a red out of it this way.

[image]

[pixlr.com](https://pixlr.com/), on the other hand, seems to have a much more Photoshop-type editing suite.

From this you can use the Fill tool [paint bucket] to block replace colour. Note that because the masked image is actually mainly grey but has a bit of white on the edges, you do this by first painting it all white, then when you paint it red it will use the entire shape…

[image]

[image]

Note the background is actually transparent, so you will see though it to whatever colour is underneath [so long as you keep it as a png & not transcode to jpg].

Comment: The key to squeezing more enhancements out of Preview's image-manipulation options is to crank them up to the max, then *save the file and re-open it*. At that point, the sliders for the image-manipulation options re-center to zero, allowing you to crank on them more. This is, essentially, the same process outlined in [Elements in Space's recent answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157185).

Comment: @CodyGray - I'd actually tried something along those lines, working from a re-saved file, but couldn't get there :\

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with just Preview.

The following method is a bit hacky, but reasonably straightforward:

1. Open the file with Preview and bring up the Adjust Colour tool

- adjust the temperature to full hot
- adjust the tint to full magenta
- adjust the sepia to full sepia
- save and close the file
  [image: image after first step]

2. Re-open the file

- adjust the exposure to full exposure
- adjust the saturation to full saturation
- save
  [image: image after second step]

Done.

---

**NB:** saving and closing the file is crucial, because it effectively “bakes-in” the colour changes; when you open the file the second time, the temperature, tint, and sepia sliders have all been reset, and the exposure and saturation sliders now apply to the *saved* colours (rather than to the original grey).